# fill gridview from html table c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have html page where there are many elements one of them is a table . How can i get the values in the table and append them to grid view i use html agility asp.net c#

This is my trial

```
HtmlNodeCollection tables = pag1.Html.SelectNodes("//table[@id='data']");

DataTable tb = new DataTable();
HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes("tr");
for (int i = 0; i <= rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes("td");
    if (cols != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            tb.Columns.Add(cols[j].InnerText);

        }

    }
}
GridView1.DataSource = tb;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

This the table

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="cols" id="page1">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">h1</th>
        <th scope="col">h2</th>
        <th scope="col">h3 </th>
        <th scope="col"> h4</th>
        <th scope="col"> h5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack()" /></td>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>value 2 </td>
        <td>value 3</td>
        <td>value 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack()" /></td>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>value 2 </td>
        <td>value 3</td>
        <td>value 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack()" /></td>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>value 2 </td>
        <td>value 3</td>
        <td>value 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so what is not working?

Comment: i get error A column named 'xxx' already belongs to this DataTable.and i cant get the header  of the table

Comment: Can I see the HTML for the table please

Comment: Are you inserting X cols for every row?

Comment: No ? i didn't insert X cols for every row?

Comment: Only the first row has the column's name. `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5`

Comment: How can i get the values in tds Abd the header name ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the columns first and then fill the table. My code may have compile issues because I am not using HTMLAgility but it will definitely guide you.

```
HtmlNodeCollection tables = pag1.Html.SelectNodes("//table[@id='data']");

DataTable tb = new DataTable();
HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[0].SelectNodes("tr");

// create the columns
HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[0].SelectNodes("th");
if (cols != null)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= cols.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        tb.Columns.Add(cols[j].InnerText);
    }
}

// Now fill the table
for (int i = 0; i <= rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var newRow = tb.NewRow();
    HtmlNodeCollection cols = rows[i].SelectNodes("td");
    if (cols != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            newRow[j] = cols[j].InnerText;
        }

    }

    // add the row to table
    tb.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
GridView1.DataSource = tb;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: what' if the table in   <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  bklkl.abc.writeWidget({'cons':'bobj.crv.newpage'; style sheet properties})

table go there  //-->

    </script>

Comment: i used this code but i get the only text in nee to get table    string xx = Regex.Replace(text, @"<[!--\W*?]*?[/]*?\w+.*?>", string.Empty).Trim();